# Is it possible to construct a quadrilateral that lies on a circle that has distinct integer edge lengths?

Tags: geometry

The title says it all:

Is it possible to construct a quadrilateral that lies on a circle that has distinct integer edge lengths (4 integers)?

You can make the radius as you like, the radius does not need to be an integer.

If the answer is yes, could you also construct one that lies on a circle that has distinct integer edge lengths and also has the two diagonal lengths being two other distinct integers (6 integers)?

Comment: One can have it all, and more! Please [see this.](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2002volume2/FG200221.pdf) There will be other information by searching for *Brahmagupta cyclic quadrilaterals*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtaining a cyclic quadrilateral with given (in our case: integer) sides is easy. Assume for simplicity that $a$ is the smallest side, and that the other sides form an acute triangle $\triangle$. Draw the circumcircle $\gamma$ of $\triangle$, then "unhinge" $\triangle$ at one of its vertices. Now slowly increase the radius of $\gamma$, all the time keeping the vertices of the three-edged hinge on $\gamma$, until the distance between the endpoinds of the hinge is $a$. Now close the hinge again by inserting an edge of length $a$.

You can obtain five pieces as wanted with the following construction: Draw a diameter of length $1$ and use it as hypotenuse for an upper and a lower right triangle with four different rational legs. Blow up until everything is integer. By carefully choosing the legs of the two right triangles it may be possible to make also the second diagonal an integer, but this requires computations.